# How to pass Google sign in object to another android activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I integrated Google Sign-In in my android app. Now I want to implement Sign-out operation (Sign-out button) in a different activity, with respect to the one where the sign-in button is present.
Following [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect), in order to sign out users I have to call `GoogleSignInClient` object, which was obtained in sign-in phase.

How can I pass this object to another activity inside an Intent? Is this the right procedure to follow, or is there another way to achive this?

Here is my code:

**FirstActivity.java**

```
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google button clicked!");
            signIn();
            break;
    }
}
private void updateUI(@Nullable GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if(account != null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        String email = account.getEmail();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass the object, as you can use the [`GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn#getLastSignedInAccount(android.content.Context)) method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.

For more information:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people